# Difference between defer call a function directly and call it in an anonymous function?

Tags: go

I got some code like this.

```
import (
  "fmt"
)

func ShowResult(result []string) {
  fmt.Println(result)
}

func main() {
  result := []string{}
  defer func() {
    ShowResult(result)
  }()
  defer ShowResult(result)
  result = append(result, "test")
}
```

And the result is:

```
[]
[test]
```

So could anyone tell me what is difference between calling a function directly and calling it in an anonymous function when defer?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The function arguments are evaluated when it is deferred. From the documentation

> Each time a "defer" statement executes, the function value and parameters to the call are evaluated as usual and saved anew but the actual function is not invoked

When your deferred function is a closure, the `ShowResult` arguments are not evaluated until the closure is executed, which is immediately after the outer function returns and after the `result` value has been modified.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's exactly what I want to know.

Comment: @zhvala. Also note that the second `defer` is the first one run:
https://play.golang.org/p/KZDsDvxBaO